# overloading new/delete problem

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, static-members

This is my scenario, Im trying to overload new and delete globally. I have written my allocator class in a file called allocator.h. And what I am trying to achieve is that if a file is including this header file, my version of new and delete should be used.

So in a header file "allocator.h" i have declared the two functions

```
extern void* operator new(std::size_t size);
extern void operator delete(void *p, std::size_t size);
```

I the same header file I have a class that does all the allocator stuff,

```
class SmallObjAllocator
{
    ...
};
```

I want to call this class from the new and delete functions and I would like the class to be static, so I have done this:

```
template<unsigned dummy>
struct My_SmallObjectAllocatorImpl
{
    static SmallObjAllocator myAlloc;
};

template<unsigned dummy>
SmallObjAllocator My_SmallObjectAllocatorImpl<dummy>::myAlloc(DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE, MAX_OBJ_SIZE);

typedef My_SmallObjectAllocatorImpl<0> My_SmallObjectAllocator;
```

and in the cpp file it looks like this: allocator.cc

```
void* operator new(std::size_t size)
{

    std::cout << "using my new" << std::endl;

    if(size > MAX_OBJ_SIZE)
        return malloc(size);
    else
        return My_SmallObjectAllocator::myAlloc.allocate(size);
}

void operator delete(void *p, std::size_t size)
{
    if(size > MAX_OBJ_SIZE)
        free(p);
    else
        My_SmallObjectAllocator::myAlloc.deallocate(p, size);
}
```

The problem is when I try to call the constructor for the class SmallObjAllocator which is a static object. For some reason the compiler are calling my overloaded function new when initializing it. So it then tries to use My_SmallObjectAllocator::myAlloc.deallocate(p, size); which is not defined so the program crashes.

So why are the compiler calling new when I define a static object? and how can I solve it?

Comment: I don't get the purpose of the template construct. Why not make SmallObjAllocator a singleton and create the object in allocator.cc?

Comment: As a guess, he wants the option of doing `My_SmallObjectAllocator<1>` at some point down the line, and getting a second allocator.

Comment: What happens in `SmallObjectAllocator`'s constructor?

Comment: I think the only way to solve it is to not use template and use a singleton

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the runtime library's global `operator new` if you provide your own. So, you can't use `new` to implement `new`, not even in initialization. Using different `operator new` in different source files is a violation of the one-definition rule.

Eliminate the `new` call from the `SmallObjAllocator::SmallObjAllocator` constructor, or implement a special case activated by a global `bool new_uninitialized` or local `static bool new_is_recursing` flag.